# Is it okay to drop the "t" in "doesn't" in an American accent?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

I heard some people pronounce it as **doesn'** and I am curious if this pronunciation is common and okay to use in day-to-day conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a Brit who really only knows American English from TV, I'd have thought they would more commonly elide to *don't*, in a similar fashion as *ain't* from *isn't* [even though it could be argued they are dialectical].

Equally, in the UK, *doesn't* will often be elided to *dunt* [or in some accents to *don't*].  *Isn't* would be elided to *int*, in the same vein. [I've never seen these written, only spoken.]
*Isn't it* has a special case of being elided further, to *innit*.

There seems to be a commonality of dropping the *s* rather than the *t*, which may still remain as a glottal stop.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to "elision":

> the omission of a sound or syllable when speaking (as in I'm, let's) [Lexico](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.lexico.com/definition/elision&ved=2ahUKEwjOp-Twyrj4AhUp7nMBHRTMCnMQFnoECAQQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2tWmO9PeMPmaLnHU8bEolv)

But "doesn't" is always more commonly used.

You can use **doesn'** in day to day conversations, but it's better to stick with **doesn't**.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. Americans "flap" t only when it occurs between vowels (corroborated by the top answer in your link). Sounds getting dropped at the end of words is common, but unrelated.

Comment: Oh sorry, then what is it supposed to be? (My bad @the-baby-is-you)

Comment: The fanciest term you'll get from me is "elision". All I know is it's a common phenomenon. I can say "doesn'" is found in both AmE and BrE.

Answer (score 0):

Speech as in the example is not a  general feature in American English.

"American accent", however, is not a single accent, but  many.
For example, among speakers of  [African-American Vernacular English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English), a range of dialects common for many Black Americans, may occur speech as in the example.

The effect may be described from the following passage in the article from Wikipedia:

> Final consonants may be deleted (although there is a great deal of variation between speakers in this regard). Most often, /t/ and /d/ are deleted. As with other dialects of English, final /t/ and /k/ may reduce to a glottal stop. Nasal consonants may be lost while nasalization of the vowel is retained (e.g., find may be pronounced [fãː]). More rarely, /s/ and /z/ may also be deleted.

As suggested, AAVE is not a prescription followed by everyone within a group. The specific effect is simply one observed among certain individuals. As noted also, the same effect may appear in other dialects outside of AAVE.